# Docker on Mathematica, Windows OS

Tags: warning-messages, windows

I've been trying to learn how to run some docker-dependent scripts in Mathematica.

Every time I try to run the script, I get the same error:

```
RunProcess::pnfd: Program docker not found.  Check Environment["PATH"].
```

When troubleshooting, I tried the simpler command

```
RunProcess[{"docker", "version"}]
```

which, using cmd, should yield a "valid" answer. However, I just get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `RunProcess[{"docker.exe", "version"}]` work for you?  `RunProcess` will search the path but it does not default the extension.

Comment: @WReach This most definitely works. I feel stupid for not testing that first, damm. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @WReach, a solution has been found. Apparently, all that it takes is to specify the windows extension, ".exe". As such, his command

```
RunProcess[{"docker.exe","version"}]
```

yields the expected result

```
<|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.22
 Version:           20.10.12
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.12
 Git commit:        e91ed57
 Built:             Mon Dec 13 11:44:07 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.5.1 (74721)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.12
 API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.12
  Git commit:       459d0df
  Built:            Mon Dec 13 11:43:56 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 contained:
  Version:          1.4.12
  GitCommit:        7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
", "StandardError" -> ""|>
```